# Convert API failing in certain situations

Tags: convertapi

We have a site that uses ConvertAPI to create PDFs and download them.  They are working in most instances but are failing with large files in certain circumstances.  Here's what I could gather:

1: it only happens with a large PDF.
2: it only happens on the mac
3: it appears to have a commonality with Acrobat where Acrobat's plugin called "Web2PDF" is listed as "loaded: no" on the two machines that are not correctly allowing the ConvertAPI code to work.  There's another mac where it DOES work in our office, but that mac is working fine.

Anyone seen this before?  Help?

Thanks.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say for sure what is the problem, as there is no information about which command is used. However, the similar problem occurs with large files if you are using the ConvertApi with a secure **https** URL instead of the **http**, as in this case:

[Powerpoint upload stops at ~9MB with cURL -F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030675/powerpoint-upload-stops-at-9mb-with-curl-f)

Please let us know if changing to the http URL helps with the problem.